# Image is not responsive from the slider gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the photos of the image gallery, those does not show **responsive(see only the left part of the photo...)**. I made the slider image to be responsive with the text and the div size, but the photo still has the some size (600x360)

**exemple.php**

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
<a href="/test.php"><img src="/images/photo1.jpg"  alt="Message to appear on the image slider"></a>
<a href="/test2.php"><img src="/images/photo2.jpg"  alt="Text to appear on the image slider"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div{box-sizing:content-box;}
#sliderFrame{position:relative;width:600px;margin:0 auto;}
#slider, #slider div.sliderInner{width:600px;height:366px;}
#slider{background-image:(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;position:relative;margin:0 auto;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);box-shadow:0px 1px 5px #999999;}
#slider a.imgLink, #slider div.video{z-index:2;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;}
#slider .video{background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg, #slider div.mc-caption-bg2{position:absolute;width:100%;height:auto;padding:20px 0;left:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:3;overflow:hidden;font-size:0;}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg{background:Black;}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg2{background:none;}
#slider div.mc-caption{font:bold 26px/20px Arial;color:#EEE;z-index:4;text-align:center;background:none;}
#slider div.mc-caption a{color:#FB0;}
#slider div.mc-caption a:hover{color:#DA0;}
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper{top:380px;text-align:center;background:none;position:relative;z-index:5;}
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div{width:11px;height:11px;font-size:0;color:White;display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;margin:0 8px;background-image:url(../images/bullet.png);}
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div.active{background-position:0 -11px;}
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div:hover{ background-image:url(../images/bullet-hover.png)}
#slider div.loading{width:100%;height:100%;background:transparent url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;filter:alpha(opacity=60);opacity:0.6;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:9;}
#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b{position:absolute;border:none;display:none;}
#slider div.sliderInner{overflow:hidden;-webkit-transform:rotate(0.000001deg);position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio{display:none;}
#slider div{-webkit-transform:tran
#slate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

**small.css (responsive css)**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
#sliderFrame { max-width:100%}
    #slider, #slider div.sliderInner, #slider div.navBulletsWrapper, #slider div.navBulletsWrapper div { max-width:100%;}
    #slider div.mc-caption { font-size:12px; max-width:100%; }
    #sliderFrame #slider img{ max-width:100%; height:auto}
    #slider img{ max-width:100%; height:auto}
}
```

Comment: anyone? know how to help me with fixing the image to responsing? sorry for double post...

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw unit (1/100th of the width of the viewport.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Demo:

http://jsbin.com/rezimah/9/edit?css,output

```
max-width: 95vw;
max-height: 57.7vw
```

Comment: doesn t work... show the slider... but the image has not responsive

Comment: did you check the demo? how did you implemented it in your code?

Comment: then what went wrong? what do you mean by "image has not responsive"?

Comment: I mean, the photoes do not change the size(normal size 600x360) even if the slider photo does change the size... (like 300x160). so i see only the first 300 width pixel (half part of the photoes)

Comment: Sorry but I just don't get it. The demo does change the size of the image. Just resize your screen and you will see. https://media.giphy.com/media/l2Sq9IWfoLb0wipNe/giphy.gif